# Using baum/baum with laravel authentication

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5

I am trying to use [Baum](https://github.com/etrepat/baum) to manage hierarchy for admins in my application, but im unable to implement both baum and laravel inbuilt authentication toghether. because admin table extends `Authenticable` Class and for baum to work it needs to extend `Baum\Node` Class.

How do i achieve this?

Any help is appriciated, thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

What did you do about it?

You could have done the following:

```
class User extends Node

implements AuthenticatableContract, AuthorizableContract, CanResetPasswordContract
{
   use Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword, SoftDeletes, Notifiable;

}
```